# Angular re-routing from one state to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

When a user attempts to visit my home page, I want to be able to redirect them to a different state based on query params.

For example, if URL is: http://example.com, then load the home page. 
If URL is: http://example.com?channel=1, then don't load the home page and go to some other state right away.

Here's what I have (doesn't work):

```
$stateProvider
...
.state('default-template.home', {
    url: '/?channel&campaign',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl as vm'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        data: ['$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$state', function($rootScope, $stateParams, $state) {

            var channel = $stateParams.channel;

            // If channel is 1, redirect 
            if (channel === 1) {
                $state.go('default-template.other-state', {channel: channel});
            }
        }]
    }
})
```

The problem seems to be that while both states get kicked off ($stateChangeStart event gets kicked off), the end result is the user always ends up on the home page.

Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $location built-in service to achieve this.

Your code must have an additional state for the fake path as below

```
 $stateProvider
    ...
    .state('default-template.fake.home', {
        url: '/?channel',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/home/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl as vm'
            }
        },
    })
    .state('default-template.home', {
        url: '/?channel&campaign',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/home/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl as vm'
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            data: ['$rootScope', '$stateParams', '$state', function($rootScope, $stateParams, $state) {

                var channel = $stateParams.channel;

                // If channel is 1, redirect 
                if (channel === 1) {
                    $state.go('default-template.other-state', {channel: channel});
                }
            }]
        }
    })
```

Your HomeCtrl should use the $location service to access the url as below

```
angular.controller('HomeCtrl',function($location,$state){
            if($location.$$url= '')     //check if it is empty
                $state.go('default-template.home');
                ....................................
    })
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/peX7vSSnvwx1ngqbWDvY?p=preview)**